# Read xml content into ListView items

Tags: xml

I just wanna read out written texts in a XML file. These texts should be displayed in a ListView item. For example:

My XML-File contains I wanna be displayed as first item

This text should be read out and put into a item.

Is there any simple solution or a tutorial?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a DataGridView instead of a ListView.  I usually read XML into a datatable.  DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.ReadXml(filename);  datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I will try it thanks :-)